# Visual studio code cannot import anything from django pylint error

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a project in django , and it is working fine. But when i changed my pc i install vscode and pylint plugin and began to appear some erros `import-error`.

http://prntscr.com/na3r2t

Anything imported from django opens this error

Comment: Do you have the Pylint plugin `pylint-django` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Pylint plugin [pylint-django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/) installed to make Pylint understand the Django web framework:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Then add the following lines to your settings.json (this will load the plugin):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
]
```